# Meteor: onRendered event on image possible?

Tags: javascript, meteor, onrender

I want to check if an image has been fully loaded. So I'm using `onRendered` on the template with the image:

**template**

```
<template name="backgroundImage">
    <img class="bg blur" src="{{image}}">
</template>
```

**helper**

```
Template.backgroundImage.helpers({
    image: function() {
        return '/images/background_1.jpg';
    }
});
```

**event**

```
Template.backgroundImage.onRendered(function() {
    console.log('image loaded, start fadeOut on overlay');
});
```

My question now is if this really works? Does `onRendered` fire at the moment when the image has loaded or does it fire for just loading the html?

My aim is to fadeOut an overlay with a loading animation after the image has fully loaded. The user should see the content of the page after(!) the image has loaded.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`onRendered` will only fire after the HTML `img` tag has been rendered to the DOM, but it won't wait until the image has actually fully loaded.

You can use the `load` event to check this :

```
Template.backgroundImage.events({
  'load img'(event, template) {
    console.log(template.$('img').prop('width'));
  },
});
```